# Creating empty element if not exists

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi friends hope all are doing well. I have a problem in my xml file i.e. in one set certain elements are exist and in next set it is not exists, so i want to create those elements which are not exist in the set. Below follows my xml file. Pls. help me.

```
<Jobs>
  <Job>
    <Job_ID>80000000</Job_ID> 
    <PositionID>60000002</PositionID> 
    <Title>Development Manager - Investment Banking - Equities Business</Title> 
    <Summary>An experienced Development Manager with previous experience leading a small to mid-size team of developers in a Java/J2EE environment. A hands on role, you will be expected to manage and mentor a team of developers working on a mix of greenfield and maintenance projects.&#160;&#160; My client, a well known investment bank, requires an experienced Development Manager to join their core technology team. This t</Summary> 
    <DateActive>10/6/2009</DateActive> 
    <DateExpire>11/5/2009</DateExpire> 
    <DateUpdated>10/6/2009</DateUpdated> 
    <Country>Country</Country> 
    <State>state</State> 
    <City>city</City> 
    <PostalCode>2000</PostalCode> 
    <CompanyName>Ambition Technology</CompanyName> 
    <BuilderFields /> 
    <DisplayOptions /> 
    <AddressType>6</AddressType> 
  </Job>
  <Job>
    <Job_ID>83790557</Job_ID> 
    <PositionID>61220512</PositionID> 
    <Title>SQL/VB Analyst Programmers With Strong Client Facing Skills $60 - $80K</Title> 
    <Summary>Excellent Location New Technologies Career Potential My client is a fast paced  IT company in Consultancy based in Inner West of Sydney. My client is experiencing a large amount of growth due to new exciting projects which they have won due to their impressive reputation and quality of work. Due to the large amount of growth my client is experiencing they are looking to take on&#160;3 Analyst/Programmer</Summary> 
    <DateActive>10/5/2009</DateActive> 
    <DateExpire>11/4/2009</DateExpire> 
    <DateUpdated>10/5/2009</DateUpdated> 
    <Country>Australia</Country> 
    <State>NSW</State> 
    <City>Sydney</City> 
    <PostalCode>2000</PostalCode> 
    <CompanyName>Skill Quest</CompanyName> 
    <SalMin>30000</SalMin> 
    <SalMax>70000</SalMax> 
    <SalType>Per Year</SalType> 
    <SalCurrency>AUD</SalCurrency> 
    <BuilderFields /> 
    <DisplayOptions /> 
    <AddressType>6</AddressType> 
  </Job>
</Jobs>
```

So, I want to add new element like SalMin,SalMax,SalType and SalCurrency as empty elements if they are not exists. And this i want to do while using xslt transformation.

Comment: I want to add new element like SalMin,SalMax,SalType and SalCurrency as empty elements if they are not exists.

Comment: At which point do you need to do this ? For example when converting from class to XML or do you already have an XML file and want to update it ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:template name="ApplyTemplatesOrCreate">
  <xsl:param name="elemName" select="''" />
  <xsl:param name="elemDefault" select="''" />

  <xsl:variable name="elem" select="*[name() = $elemName]" />

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$elem">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$elem" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:if test="$elemName != ''">
        <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
          <xsl:value-of select="$elemDefault" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

call as:

```
<xsl:call-template name="ApplyTemplatesOrCreate">
  <xsl:with-param name="elemName" select="'SalMin'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="elemDefault" select="'1000'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your respone, but sir i didn't get you that how should i use them in my existing xslt.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you didn't show your existing XSLT - a little thinking of your own can't be too much to ask.